# Can't get output from Docker using os.system command in flask app

Tags: python, docker, flask

Flask with Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04

I'm building a web app where I need to run some Python code supplied by users, and plan to use Docker to spin up temporary containers to run the code, return some output and spin down the container.

My code does not write the output to file when called by flask.

I've successfully run the command from SSH, as well as drawing up a test python script (run using the same Virtual Environment as Flask) which writes the file without issue. It's only when called via a http request that it fails.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def runScript():
    ScriptSettings = Settings()

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        key = request.form['key']
        if key == ScriptSettings.key:
            user = request.form['user']
            script = request.form['script']

            rand_str = str(random.randint(100000000, 1000000000))
            file_name = f"user-scripts/{user}-{rand_str}"
            script_file_name = file_name + ".py"
            response_file_name = file_name + ".txt"
            working_directory = "/home/USER/request-server"

            f=open(script_file_name, "w+")
            f.write(script)
            f.close()

            os.system(f'docker run -it --rm --name {user}-{rand_str} -v "$PWD":{working_directory} -w {working_directory} python:3.7-alpine python {script_file_name} > {response_file_name}')



            f=open(response_file_name, "r")
            contents = f.read()
            f.close()

            if remove_user_files:
                os.remove(script_file_name)
                os.remove(response_file_name)

            return contents
        else:
            return ""
    else:
        return ""
```

the txt file (response_file_name) should contain the output from the python code/docker. It works perfectly when run from the test script or direct command line, but just writes an empty file when called in this script with flask (http request)

Comment: I've also used os.system("python3 "+ script_file_name + "> " + response_file_name) which worked, but I need the script to be run in docker for security.

Comment: How does it fail?  Which code actually runs the script?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, thanks for your response. I've just reread the code and realised I accidentally deleted a key line when I was tidying the code to post it here - it's back in now. The script is called via a HTTP request, I'm using uSWGI and Nginx with flask.

Comment: I've taken a modified version of the code and run it directly from the server (python test.py) and it works, but when it's called from the HTTP request in this script it just writes an empty file (response_file_name)- the text file is there, just no contents.

Comment: What does this script do if the network caller passes `user=x -v/:/host -e UNUSED=`?  This needs to be rewritten to not use `os.system`, and an appropriate `subprocess` call can capture the container's output directly without needing an intermediate file; if you address the security issues here it will probably also address your immediate question.

Comment: thanks again @DavidMaze, I'm needing to get a working beta together quickly, and hoping using docker will negate most security concerns until I can spend the time to do it properly (or employ someone smarter than me) . I'll investigate subprocess again and see if I can make it work.